# Override model __init__ for an attribute which gets its value from running a method using another attribute as an argument

Tags: django, django-models

I'm new to Django and was wondering how I can change `__init__` (I assume this is the right approach) so that when I add a new object, one of the attributes 'b'  gets its value from a method that uses the value of the attribute 'a' as an argument.

For example:

I have a model `Poll`, which contains attributes `question`, and `asked_online`.  Where `asked_online` uses the value of `question` to interact with the API of a web forum to check if its already been asked there and if so sets it to the value true

Edit:

Better Example.

A model 'Tag' which contains the attribute 'name' and 'num_post'.
'num_post' uses 'name' to look up the number of posts on stack overflow that contain that tag.

This is used as an initial value for the object where web app updates the value every so often on a weekly schedule(this is just giving context).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of changing the `__init__()` method, you can implement `asked_online` as property of the class.

Example:

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    #your fields

    @property
    def asked_online(self):
        #check if self.question is asked using some method
        return True # if asked online, else False
```

Comment: Sorry, the example I gave was probably a poor one in the situation and I added another one.

I wanted to display that attribute when I output objects to the web page and thought a method would be costly (time and resources)

Comment: @user2781163, If you mean that you want to save the attribute in DB also, then probably having a method to update is better option. You can have `update_asked_online()` method to check status and update the field in DB. You can call it periodically(or once in a day etc ) using modify time in the db.